# Redis use cases

Tags: redis

I've done some projects with Redis and MongoDB but I'm not comfortable at all. I'm currently using MongoDB for storing player datas and Redis for temporary and sorted datas. I'd want to use Redis more to my projects.

**My questions**

1. Should I use Redis more for persistent datas? I'd like to know a question about this case; if I make a project that ban players from the game server, is Redis good option to use for this case?
2. What are the best use cases for Redis?
3. As I mention it above, I use MongoDB for storing player datas and map for cache their information when they're online. From what I know redis is one of the best NoSQL database for caching. Should I use Redis for caching player datas?

If you have any other idea about the topic, I'd like to know that with details.

Comment: Your question is too broad IMHO, but I will address your first point.  Redis is a _cache_, not a data store, such as a database, and so is best suited for temporary, non permanent information.  Maintaining a blacklist of users is in fact something for which Redis is very well suited, but this type of information is not necessarily persistent.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for information. I'm trying to understand what are the best use cases for Redis. If you consider I use both MongoDB and Redis, I must separate them and use correctly. As you said I don't use Redis for persistent datas for now but I'd like to save small datas in Redis. If you say I shouldn't, I won't use even small datas.

Comment: The size of the data isn't really the major issue here (it is, sort of).  If you have data which needs to be store permanently, then a cache isn't the best place for that, you should use a database.  Your suggestion to use Redis for a blacklist user cache is completely spot-on; that's a very valid use case for Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use Redis more for persistent datas?

Redis is way more than Cache and is acting as [Main database](https://redislabs.com/blog/goodbye-cache-redis-as-a-primary-database/) in many enterprises, and also supports few methods [persistency](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) like RDB and AOF.

> if I make a project that ban players from the game server, is Redis good option to use for this case?

Redis support a nice set of plugins (Modules), one of them is [RedisBloom](https://RedisBloom.io/), especially suited for quick filtering.